# Java 6 - Creating and detecting the first double value above Long.MAX_VALUE

Tags: java, casting, double, long-integer, max

Below I attempt to assign to `value` the maximum `Long` value, then add to it the minimum positive `Double` value possible.

I then try to detect that the value is greater than the maximum `Long` value.

```
Double value = new Long(Long.MAX_VALUE).doubleValue();
value += Double.MIN_VALUE;
if (value < -(new Long(Long.MAX_VALUE).doubleValue()) || value > new Long(Long.MAX_VALUE).doubleValue()) {
  // Expecting code here to execute, but it doesn't.
}
```

Studying the values involved shows that `value` has the final value of

```
9.223372036854776E18
= 9223372036854776000
```

while `Long.MAX_VALUE` has the value

```
9223372036854775807
```

Comparing these shows that `value` is greater as expected:

```
9223372036854776000 (value)
9223372036854775807 (Long.MAX_VALUE)
```

Could someone please explain why the `if` statement fails to detect this?

Sincere thanks.

Comment: If you want the next-higher `double` value, use `Math.nextUp((double) Long.MAX_VALUE)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Long.MAX_VALUE` can't be represented exactly as a double. The closest available double value is `9223372036854775808`.

Adding `Double.MIN_VALUE` to that number (10^-1074) does not change anything because the closest double value to `9223372036854775808 + 10^-1074` still is `9223372036854775808`.

Using @PeterLawrey's code, you can see that the next available double is `9223372036854777856` (which is equal to `Long.MAX_VALUE + 2048`).

Note: your double is actually equal to `9223372036854775808`, which gets **printed** as `9.223372036854776E18`. You can see it with the following code:

```
double d = Long.MAX_VALUE;
BigDecimal bd= new BigDecimal(d);
System.out.println(bd);
```

Comment: Thank you for editing to make your original response more thorough. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Adding a very small value to a large value is the same as adding nothing.

I suspect what you had in mind is

```
double d = Long.MAX_VALUE;
// get the next represented value.
double d1 = Double.longBitsToDouble(Double.doubleToLongBits(d)+1);
System.out.println(d > Long.MAX_VALUE);
System.out.println(d1 > Long.MAX_VALUE);
```

prints

```
false
true
```

Comment: Thank you very much for providing the correct implementation. Strictly speaking, assylias has answered the question I asked - 'why the if fails'. But I was also silently hoping for the correct solution, so cheers :)

Comment: I just found a much simpler way to achieve this. The following pattern can be used when combining any floating point with any non-f.p., or combining two f.p. : `double value = (double)Long.MAX_VALUE; value += Math.ulp(value);` This is courtesy of a response I received here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12356793/java-6-creating-and-detecting-the-first-double-value-above-float-max-value

Comment: A new winner: `Math.nextUp(value)`. See thread link in my comment preceding this one.