# Java 6 - Creating and detecting the first Double value above Float.MAX_VALUE

Tags: java, floating-point, double

I would like to create the `Double` whose value is closest to, but greater than, `Float.MAX_VALUE`.

I've just written a question similar to this but for `Double` and `Long.MAX_VALUE`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12355839/java-6-creating-and-detecting-the-first-double-value-above-long-max-value).

How can I repeat the conversion for `Double` and `Float.MAX_VALUE` using the standard Java 6 API?

My attempt is below, but is incorrect it seems:

```
Long longValue = Long.valueOf(Float.floatToIntBits(Float.MAX_VALUE));
Double value = Double.longBitsToDouble(Double.doubleToLongBits(longValue)+1);

if (value < -Float.MAX_VALUE || value > Float.MAX_VALUE) {
    // Code here should execute but does not.
}
```

Sincere thanks.

Comment: Did you try printing `longValue` and `value` to see what you actually got?

Comment: @Jim I already know the result is wrong, looking at the value to show me this doesn't identify the flaw in my bit translation. If you've downvoted then please undo it, this question is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Math.nextUp((double) Float.MAX_VALUE);
```

It's not only equivalent to the most efficient solution, but...it makes it pretty obvious what result you should expect.

Comment: This is too concise to pass up - thank you for sharing! Now all the two-line uses of `Math.ulp` can become one-liners :) Excellent knowledge.

Answer (score 5):

```
Double val = (double)Float.MAX_VALUE;
val += Math.ulp(val);
```

This may also work (correction of your example), but not entirely sure:

```
Double val = Double.longBitsToDouble(Double.doubleToLongBits(Float.MAX_VALUE)+1);
```

Comment: Thank you very much - `Math.ulp` is a much simpler solution to these questions than manually converting bits into a non-floating point representation just to be able to add one bit! Is there a reverse function of `ulp` also, to retrieve the next lowest f.p.?

Comment: @KomodoDave - not that i know of.

Comment: `Float.MIN_VALUE` is the smallest positive value, not the most negative. See API docs. Confusing I agree, given `Integer.MIN_VALUE` is the most negative, not the smallest positive.

Comment: @KomodoDave it's because IEEE754 floating point uses what is a rough analogue to sign-and-magnitude representation for numbers. As a result, the most negative value means little, since it will be equal to `-MAX_VALUE` (note this does *not* apply to 2's complement, hence why that doesn't hold for `Integer.MIN_VALUE` and `MAX_VALUE`). Instead, it makes more sense to think of the minimal value of *magnitude*.

Comment: @oldrinb Yes, I understand the representation, am aware of sign+mantissa+exponent. It still seems unnecessarily confusing to have equivalent naming. They should have names like `MOST_NEGATIVE_VALUE`, `MOST_POSITIVE_VALUE`, `LEAST_POSITIVE_VALUE` to be truly clear.

Comment: @jtahlborn Louis Wasserman has provided a more concise solution for which I must give credit.